# Access Google Notes using Android API (Java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gmail, inbox

I want to make an Android Application in Eclipse that accesses the Notes Inbox in Gmail and can edit, create, or delete them. How would I do this? In iOS there is a preinstalled application that does this. Is there an API that I could use to do this in Android?

Comment: hey did you find any information about that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey actually I was looking for the same thing for Node.Js/Javascript and basically found out that you can just access the Gmail account through IMAP and that gives you access to any folder you need. So just use IMAP to access Gmail and then retrieve all the notes from the Notes folder. Just in case, here's the module for Node.Js: https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap